# Parse response from XML or JSON API with Httpful PHP

Tags: php, json, xml, httpful

I am using the [Httpful PHP library](http://phphttpclient.com/) to GET data from an API using either JSON or XML. My code is very simple and returns the response from the url with basic authentication.

```
$url = "API_URL";
$response = \Httpful\Request::get($url)
    ->expectsXml() // or ->expectsJson()
    ->authenticateWith('USERNAME', 'PASSWORD')
    ->send();
echo "{$response}";
```

I am successful in displaying the entire response output, but how do I return a single variable?

For example, if I only wanted to receive city from each person, what would this look like? I have tried `echo "{$response->body->city}";` but it does not seem to work.

The XML that is returned by the api is formatted as such:

```
<ArrayOfPERSON xmlns:i="xxx" xmlns="xxx">
  <PERSON>
    <CITY></CITY>
    <COUNTRY></COUNTRY>
    <STATE></STATE>
    <STREET1></STREET1>
    <STREET2></STREET2>
    <WORKPHONE></WORKPHONE>
    <ZIP></ZIP>
  </PERSON>
</ArrayOfPERSON>
```

And switching the header to JSON has the data formatted as:

```
[
  {
    "STREET1": ""
    "STREET2": ""
    "CITY": ""
    "STATE": ""
    "ZIP": ""
    "COUNTRY": ""
    "WORKPHONE": ""
  }
]
```

Comment: @jszobody Yes, this worked! It also appears to be case sensitive. `$response->body[0]->CITY` is the correct output.

Comment: awesome, glad to help! I just posted it as an answer below, can you accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at your JSON structure, it appears the response is nested.

So I believe you'll need to access the body like this:

```
echo $response->body[0]->STREET1;
```

---

Side note: It's always useful to examine your `$response` by just doing a `var_dump($response)` when you can't figure out how to navigate it. Just looking at the resulting structure usually makes the answer quite clear!